# Print php data in new tab

Tags: php

I have a simple php code like this:

```
    //index.php
    $file  = fil1.txt;
    //open file using fopen...
    echo $file;
```

What should I do if I need to print my file data in new tab in another php file(e.x. result.php) ?

This is real my example of code:

```
function elementStart($parser, $name, $attrs) {
global $depth;

echo str_repeat("&nbsp;", $depth * 0); 
//echo "<b>$name</b><br>";     

$depth++; 

    foreach ($attrs as $attr => $value) {
        echo str_repeat("&nbsp;", $depth * 0); 

        echo $value.'<br>';
    }
}

function elementStr($parser, $str) {
    if (strlen(trim($str)) > 0) {
        global $depth;

        echo str_repeat("&nbsp;", $depth * 0); 
        echo $str.'<br>'; 
    }
}

function elementEnd($parser, $name) {
    global $depth;

    $depth--;
}

require_once 'connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{

$db = new database('localhost', 'root', '', 'database1');
$val = mysql_escape_string($_POST['xml1']); 
$db->query("SELECT * FROM xmltable1 WHERE xmlvalue LIKE '%$val%' LIMIT 1");
if($_POST['submit1'])
{



    if($dbase->numRows() == 0){
        echo 'No rows';
    }
    else{
        foreach($db->rows() as $name){
            //echo $name['xmlvalue'];

            define('FOLDER_PATH', 'C:user/folder1/xmld/');
            $full_path = FOLDER_PATH.$name['xmldata'];
            //echo $full_path;
                    $depth = 0;
                    $file  = $full_path;

                    $xml_parser = xml_parser_create();

                    xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser, "elementStart", "elementEnd");
                    xml_set_character_data_handler($xml_parser, "elementStr");


                    while ($data = fgets($fp)) {

                    thexml_parser_free($thexml_parser);

            }

        }
    }

$dbase->disconnect();
}
```

In my functions there are echo. And of course I get echo in current page, but I need echo in new tab.

Comment: On your index.php is a link to result.php where result.php is the that will open the file.

Comment: have you tried html <a href="/* Link */" target="_blank"> ?

Comment: and in the link put target="_blank"  to get the new tab

Answer (score 1):

The only way to pass data to another PHP file in another window (or tab) is by using sessions.

At the top of both your PHP files, *start a session*:

```
session_start();
```

In your *index.php* assign the file data to a session variable:

```
$_SESSION['file_data'] = $file_contents;
```

In your *results.php*, print out the data:

```
echo $_SESSION['file_data'];
```

Comment: spajce, it's interesting solution. I just edited my example of code. How to apply your variant to my code?

Comment: It's not his variant, it's mine.  He just added code tags to my answer.

Comment: Ups, sorry yes! Tell me please, how to apply your  variant with sessions using my code ?

Answer (score 1):

Open an new tab is not PHP should do, you can try using javascripntk to achieve like this:

```
echo <<<EOF
<script>
var win = window.open('about:blank');
var doc = win.document;
doc.write('{$yourdata}');
</script>
EOF;
```